# Dependency Injection and Singleton in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, ionic2, singleton

I'm working on ionic 3 and Angular 4 with typescript and I'm confused on what needs to be done.

Let me first present what I have:

I have a class that has a `private static _instance: ClassName` property.
This is the constructor: `private constructor(private platform: Platform, private file: File){}` 
and then I have a static get instance property

```
static get instance() {
    if(!ClassName._instance){
        ClassName._instance = new ClassName();
    }
    return ClassName._instance;
}
```

now my question is, the new-ing is not allowed inside the get instance() because of Platform and File service being injected in the class's constructor. How do i go on about creating a new instance or solve this problem? What could be a possible scenario if I make my injectors optional? 
`constructor(private platform?: Platform, private file?: File){}`

Comment: can i just use the references from import without injecting in the constructor?

Comment: I haven't had the opportunity to try it but I'm pretty sure "value providers" is what you're looking for https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#value-provider

Comment: You can't really use dependency injection for a global static singleton like this.  What is your goal?  Why does this have to be a global static singleton?

Answer (score 0):

If anybody stumbles across this question then you can make your injectable singleton by just declaring it inside providers array in app.module.ts. That maintains a single instance across the app. Any time you have lazy loaded modules and declare your injectable inside the providers of that lazily loaded module, you are creating multiple instances of the injectable.